# Gwt Mockito: @RunWith(GwtMockitoTestRunner.class) causes Exception

Tags: java, gwt, mockito, noclassdeffounderror, presenter

I'm doing a project with gwt at the moment. I have to test a presenter using Eclipse Luna, JUnit and Mockito and have problems doing anything.

After I failed with mockito I discovered GwtMockito and tried that. I used this example to get started: [Github GwtMockito example](https://github.com/google/gwtmockito/blob/master/gwtmockito-sample/src/test/java/sample/MyWidgetTest.java)

My Test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(GwtMockitoTestRunner.class)
public class GamePresenterTest {

@GwtMock private GameServiceAsync gameService;
@GwtMock private LobbyPresenter lobbyPresenter;
@GwtMock private EventBus eventBus;
@GwtMock private Display gameView;
@GwtMock private User user;
@GwtMock private Player player;
@GwtMock private ClickEvent event;

private GamePresenter presenter;
private String username = "name";
private String gameTitle = "title";

@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.out.println("TODO: set up");
}

@Test
public void testActionTableClicked() {
    System.out.println("TODO: add test");
}
}
```

When I run it I get this

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/NotFoundException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.NotFoundException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 18 more
```

When I remove the `@RunWith(GwtMockitoTestRunner.class)` I get another message that tells me I should use initMocks, but I don't how to do that, too.
Without `@RunWith(GwtMockitoTestRunner.class)` and the `@GwtMock` stuff everything works fine of course.

I hope someone can help, because my project ends in a few weeks.

Comment: Get yourself a dependency management tool like maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need `javassist-<version>.jar`. Add it to your classpath and it should work

Comment: This did it. Thanks a lot. I am very bad at testing stuff in gwt, but now I can go on with my tasks and try to handle other exceptions, that'll come. Thank you :)